# pass multiple value to <isNotEmpty> property

Tags: java, sql, ibatis

I'm new to iBatis. I would like if it's possible to pass multiple values into  xml.

for example,

```
    <select id="getSth" resultClass="Object" parameterClass="Object">
    select * from table
<isNotEmpty property="startDate, endDate" prepend="AND">
    date_start >= #startDate# AND date_end <= #endDate#
</isNotEmpty>
</select>
```

is it possible like that? if not, any method??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, It is not possible to use multiple values in property attribute. But you can use nested tag to achieve this.

```
<select id="getSth" resultClass="Object" parameterClass="Object">
     select * from table
     <isNotEmpty property="startDate" >
         <isNotEmpty property="endDate" >
            where date_start &gt;= #startDate# AND date_end &lt;= #endDate#
         </isNotEmpty>
    </isNotEmpty>
</select>
```

PS: you cannot use less than '<' , greater than '>' symbol inside the query. Instead use `&lt;` and `&gt;` respectively.

Answer (score 1):

```
<select id="getSth" resultClass="Object" parameterClass="Object">
 select * from table
 <isNotEmpty property="startDate" >
     <isNotEmpty property="endDate" >
        where date_start &gt;= #startDate# AND date_end &lt;= #endDate#
     </isNotEmpty>
     <isNotEmpty property="endDate" >
        where date_start &gt;= #startDate# AND date_end &lt;= #endDate#
     </isNotEmpty>
</isNotEmpty>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use multiple rules but you can nest one rule in another rule. In this way you can nest (n) number of rules. So the nested fragment of your query only runs when all the rules are met (that is true).

So this is the fix

```
<select id="getSth" resultClass="Object" parameterClass="Object">
SELECT * FROM TABLE
<isNotEmpty property="STARTDATE">
    <isNotEmpty property="ENDDATE">
          WHERE DATE_START &gt;= #STARTDATE# AND DATE_END &lt;= #ENDDATE#
    <isNotEmpty>
<isNotEmpty>
</select>
```

You can also check for other conditions if you want, such that you can have mixed rules.

So i can check that my STARTDATE,ENDDATE aren't null isNotNull before checking for isNotEmpty. In this way IBATIS will not bother checking other conditions if the outtermost condition is false.

```
<select id="getSth" resultClass="Object" parameterClass="Object">
SELECT * FROM TABLE
<isNotNull property="STARTDATE">
    <isNotNull property="ENDDATE">
        <isNotEmpty property="STARTDATE">
            <isNotEmpty property="ENDDATE">
                  WHERE DATE_START &gt;= #STARTDATE# AND DATE_END &lt;= #ENDDATE#
            <isNotEmpty>
        <isNotEmpty>
    </isNotNull>
</isNotNull>
</select>
```

Sometimes your condition fragment may grow so big and maybe confusing to read,understand and document. You may want to separate your rules from the main select statement using IBATIS sql tag.

```
<sql id="getStartDateAndEndDateRuleFragment">
<isNotNull property="STARTDATE">
    <isNotNull property="ENDDATE">
        <isNotEmpty property="STARTDATE">
            <isNotEmpty property="ENDDATE">
                  WHERE DATE_START &gt;= #STARTDATE# AND DATE_END &lt;= #ENDDATE#
            <isNotEmpty>
        <isNotEmpty>
    </isNotNull>
</isNotNull>
</sql>
```

Then your final select tag will look like this.

```
<select id="getSth" resultClass="Object" parameterClass="Object">
SELECT * FROM TABLE <include refid="getStartDateAndEndDateRuleFragment" />
</select>
```

This is cleaner and less confusing.In this way others co-developers working in your team can just simple eye-ball it and figure out what it is doing.